# R predict missing values

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, missing-data, predict

How should I predict missing values NA based on other values in R? Mean value is not enough.
[image: values]

All values are dependable - columns values are tree scope rate, rows are three height in meters.

My excel file is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=92548782987858181935).

Is there any possible way to do that? I've been trying with predict function with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about this but here is one. I also tried using it on your dataset but it's either too small, has too many linear combinations or something else because it's not converging.

Amelia - http://fastml.com/impute-missing-values-with-amelia/

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars1<-mtcars[rep(row.names(mtcars),10),] #increasing dataset

#inserting NAs into dataset
insert_nas <- function(x) {
    len <- length(x)
    n <- sample(1:floor(0.2*len), 1) #randomly choosing # of missing obs
    i <- sample(1:len, n) #choosing which to make missing
    x[i] <- NA 
    x
}

mtcars1 <- sapply(mtcars1, insert_nas)

ords = c( 'cyl','hp','vs','am','gear','carb' ) #integers - your dataset has no integers so don't specify this
#idvars = c( 'these', 'will', 'be', 'ignored' )
#noms = c( 'some', 'nominal', 'columns' ) #categorical

a.out = amelia( mtcars1,  ords = ords)

a.out$imputations[[1]]

#you can also ensemble your imputations if you'd like. Here we ensemble 3 of the 5 returned imputations
final_data<-as.data.frame(sapply(colnames(a.out$imputations[[1]]),function(i)
    rowMeans(cbind(a.out$imputations[[1]][,i],a.out$imputations[[2]][,i],a.out$imputations[[3]][,i]))))
```